# Word boundery in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, word-boundary

In PHP [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_diacritics) before and after letters make word boundary (`\b`), that is not desired behavior. Is it normal among other programming languages? (I know most languages have issues with `\b` and `\w`) How should I solve this issue effectively?

From Unicode perspective which Unicode categories make word boundaries?

It is an example:

```
<?php
 preg_match_all('#\bج\b#u','مَجْل',$t); // the font of this site does not display diacritics
var_dump($t);
```

Comment: What actually is considered a “word” character is dependent on the _locale_ settings. And maybe you should look at the Unicode character properties as well, http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: [locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale) not local.

Answer (score 1):

In PCRE:

> \d  any character that \p{Nd} matches (decimal digit)
>
> \s  any character that \p{Z} matches, plus HT, LF, FF, CR
>
> \w  any character that \p{L} or \p{N} matches, plus underscore

According to `\w` definition you can infer `\b` definition in Unicode mode. So even for string  `Åström` (decomposed characters) that logical has two word boundary multiple word boundary will detected `*A*̊*stro*̈*m*`.

Comment: I don't see the relation between your answer and your question, your question was about Arabic diacritics. By the way, was my answer not helpful ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV There is no difference between Arabic and Latin diacritics in the question.

Comment: ok, so how do you make it work with the example in your question ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV `\w` => `\w\pM`

Answer (score 0):

This is just a workaround:

```
preg_match_all('#(\p{M}*\p{Arabic}*\p{M}*)*ج(\p{M}*\p{Arabic}*\p{M}*)*#u','مَجْل جميل testجواد',$t); // the font of this site does not display diacritics
print_r(array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $t)));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => مَجْل
            [1] => جميل
            [2] => جواد
        )

)
```

I found out that `\p{M}` will match **teshkil**, and `\p{Arabic}` will match an **Arabic letter**.